# Database software solution

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ms-access, database-recommendation

Our company has user data (name, email, phone number, systems of access, AD username) in a large Excel workbook. The Excel workbook is becoming very slow because of the 1000s of entries in it, and we're looking for an alternative solution.

I was think Microsoft Access because of the ease of use and ability to quickly make forms and reports, but my boss is worried about Access becoming end of lifed soon. Anyone have another solution for this? I know a little SQL, so that's an option, but not a preferred option.

Comment: Well, SQL Express is free and it's a good database plateform. It does have limitation but if your data was holding in an excel, SQL shouldn't have any issue with it. There is also a huge community that can help you with SQL.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum, why do you think MS-Access will be deprecated soon?

Comment: @McNets Hi :) I read a few articles about Access being removed from Web Apps and Web Databases in Office 365, and how that was the beginning of the end.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/20366

Comment: Surely you can just use Active Directory for this?

Comment: @Colin No there's a lot more fields that we track besides the ones I listed.

Comment: Are you looking for "Identity Management Software"?

Comment: @rocky But isn’t that the whole point of a directory server — to be able to add fields?

Comment: Storing this sort of information in an Excel workbook seems risky from security perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server express is a good choice.  You can also create a very low cost (a few bucks a month) database only on Azure.  In that scenario there would be no maintenance.  I would argue SQL is what you are dealing with when working on data and Excel can easily connect to a table.  This may be your best solution.

Comment: Seconding Azure for the ease of managing backups